# Trying to get slider to stay within background image border and still remain responsive

Tags: html, css

I have been trying(very hard)to get this slider to remain inside the black area of the background image. I can do it if I set all the widths etc. to fixed values but
then the page is no longer responsive. When I try using percentages everything scales with the browser but the slider jumps around...Mock up is running at:
http://www.skaliwag.com.au

Comment: seems like a lot of the questions I see here would be off topic then. many of the posts asking for help with css and html are asking what is wrong with their code. how is this different?

Answer (score 2):

Hello i think i fixed your problem.

It's very simple. You just need to change two values in your css: the `.rslides margin to 65% auto` and remove the margin-top of the image. Then it should look like this.

The slider div:

```
.rslides {
     position: relative;
     list-style: none;
     overflow: hidden;
     width: 70%;
     padding: 0M
     margin: 65% auto;    
}
```

and the image:

```
.rslides img {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
    border: solid 1px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    position: relative;
}
```

Hope it was helpfull :)

Comment: awesome. its in the right spot and responisive but the slider seems to have picked up a hiccup on transition and It needs to be around the size of the frame area. sorry if I didn't make that clear

Comment: For me it works without hopping... but its really difficult to adjust the size, because the way how you coded it is really strange. I'd recommend to you to rework the whole site and. Clean code always solves the problems.